# Stokes' Theorem verified problem

Tags: stokes-theorem

[image: Figure]

For the given vector field
$$\vec{H(r)} = rcos( \phi - \frac{\pi}{4} ) \vec{ a_{r} } +sin \phi  \vec{ a_{ \phi }} $$

**a)** Calculate line integral of $\vec{H(r)} $  over the close path $ \Gamma $ with corners at ABCD on xy-plane shown in Figure.

**b)**  Confirm the result of the line integral by using Stokes' theorem.-

i solved but I couldn't verified, I don't understand where I am doing wrong.

My solution:

$\vec{H(r)} = rcos( \phi - \frac{\pi}{4} ) \vec{ a_{r} } +sin \phi  \vec{ a_{ \phi }} $

**a)** $ \int_A^B  \vec{H(r)}.\vec{ a_{r}} .dr |_{\phi  =  \frac{ \pi }{4}} +  \int_B^C  \vec{H(r)}.r.\vec{ a_{ \phi }} d \phi  |_{r=1} +\int_C^D  \vec{H(r)}\vec{ a_{ r }} dr   |_{ \phi = \frac{ 3\pi }{4}}  +\int_D^A  \vec{H(r)}r\vec{ a_{ \phi }} d \phi  |_{r=2}$

then,

$\int_{r=2}^1  rcos(\phi - \frac{ \pi }{4} )  |_{ \phi = \frac{ \pi }{4}} + \left(\int_{\frac{ 3\pi }{2}}^\frac{ \pi }{4}  sin\phi.d \phi.r |_{r=2}] + \int_{\frac{ 3\pi }{4}}^\frac{ 3\pi }{2}  sin \phi. d \phi. r )  |_{ r=2}\right ) + \left( \int_{r=1}^2  rcos(\phi - \frac{ \pi }{4} )  |_{ \phi = \frac{ 3\pi }{4}} \right ) + [\int_{\frac{ 3\pi }{2}}^\frac{ 3\pi }{4}  sin\phi.d\phi.r |_{r=1} + \int_{\frac{ \pi }{4}}^\frac{ 3\pi }{2}  sin\phi.d\phi.r |_{r=1}] $

$\therefore $

= $  \frac{ r^2 }{2} |_{ 2}^1 + \left (2(-cos\phi)|_{ \frac{ 3\pi }{2}}^\frac{ \pi }{4} + 2(-cos\phi)|_{ \frac{ 3\pi }{4}}^\frac{ 3\pi }{2}  \right ) +  \left ( (-cos\phi)|_{ \frac{ 3\pi }{2}}^\frac{ 3\pi }{4} + (-cos\phi)|_{ \frac{ \pi }{4}}^\frac{ 3\pi }{2}  \right )$

=$-\frac{ 3 }{2} - \sqrt{2}$

**b)** $\bigtriangledown \times \vec{H} = \vec{a_z}  \left ( {\frac{ sin \phi }{r}} - sin(  \frac{ \pi }{4}- \phi) \right )$

$\int_{S} \bigtriangledown \times \vec{H}.d\vec{s} = rd \phi dr  \left ( {\frac{ sin \phi }{r}} - sin(  \frac{ \pi }{4}- \phi) \right )$ $\Rightarrow $

$ = \left( \int_{r=1}^2 \int_{\frac{ 3\pi }{2}}^ \frac { \pi }{4}sin \phi d \phi dr -  \int_{r=1}^2 \int_{\frac{ 3\pi }{2}}^ \frac { \pi }{4} sin (\frac{ \pi }{4} - \phi) r d \phi dr \right ) + \left( \int_{r=1}^2 \int_{\frac { 3\pi }{4}}^\frac{ 3\pi }{2} sin \phi d \phi dr -  \int_{r=1}^2 \int_{\frac { 3\pi }{4}}^\frac{ 3\pi }{2} sin (\frac{ \pi }{4} - \phi) r d \phi dr \right )$

then,

$ \left( (-cos\phi)|_{ \frac{ 3\pi }{2}}^\frac{ \pi }{4}.r|_{1}^2  - cos(\frac{ \pi }{4} - \phi) |_{ \frac{ 3\pi }{2}}^\frac{ \pi }{4}.\frac{ r^2 }{2} |_{ 1}^2 \right ) + \left( (-cos\phi)|_{ \frac{ 3\pi }{4}}^\frac{ 3\pi }{2}.r|_{1}^2  - cos(\frac{ \pi }{4} - \phi) |_{ \frac{ 3\pi }{4}}^\frac{ 3\pi }{2}.\frac{ r^2 }{2} |_{ 1}^2 \right )$

$=-\frac{ 3 }{2} - \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Ahh, those pernicious sign errors! One mistake is that the limits of $\phi$ are$$\frac \pi 4$$ and $$-\frac {5\pi}4$$ not $\frac {3\pi}2$

Comment: @PaulSinclair hmm thank you, actually I found -3/2-sqrt(2) look: https://i.imgur.com/ytETylm.jpg but my limits still 3pi/2 how is it possible? :D

Comment: $\frac {3\pi}2$ is the direction of the negative $y$-axis. Where do you see a limit in that direction in your graph?? The line $AB$ is at $\frac \pi 4$, the line $CD$ is at $\frac {3\pi}4$, but as the curves you are following pass over the positive $x$-axis, you would be well advised to subtract $2\pi$ and use $-\frac{5\pi}4 instead to avoid having a discontinuity (it actually doesn't affect this integration, but there are others that it would, so it's better to be in the habit of thinking this way).

Comment: @PaulSinclair ok thank you, I'll solve again this limits. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

$ \int_{r=2}^1  r.cos(\phi-\frac{ \pi }{4}) .dr |_{\phi  =  \frac{ \pi }{4}} +  \int_{\phi=\frac{ \pi }{4}}^\frac{ -5\pi }{4} sin\phi.d\phi.r  |_{r=1} + \int_{\phi=\frac{ 3\pi }{4}}^\frac{ 9\pi }{4} sin\phi.d\phi.r  |_{r=2} $

$=-\frac{ 3 }{2} - \sqrt{2}$ Line integral boundaries:

B $\Rightarrow $ C   $\frac{ \pi }{4}, \frac{ -5\pi }{4}$

D $\Rightarrow $ A   $\frac{ 3\pi }{4}, \frac{ 9\pi }{4}$

---

stokes' is verified, boundaries: $ \phi= \frac{ 3\pi }{4} \Rightarrow \frac{ 3\pi }{2}$ and $ \phi= \frac{ 3\pi }{2} \Rightarrow \frac{ \pi }{4}$